# How to customize Topics on Records table

Tags: customization, topics

I want to add more columns at topics on records table, but I can't find where can do this. Please help me, thanks.

[image]

Topics on Records Overview: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=basics_topics_records_overview.htm&language=en_US

Comment: It's even worse for custom objects - the only colum available by default is Name. Is this configurable?